# String convert to utf8 but still showing issue to display

Tags: ios, swift, string, utf-8, utf

I try to convert utf8 string but its not working.

I getting **Hof CafÃ©**  and I have to show **Hof Café** and tried following code.

```
let str = String(utf8String:(objPOI.name?.cString(using: .utf8))!)
iCell.lblNamePOI.text =  str  ?? ""
```

Comment: That conversion makes no sense, it does not change anything. – Where does `objPOI.name` come from? The problem should be fixed where you create that string.

Comment: I tried to display as its but it not working. @MartinR objPOI is model and name its string which store a value. if its no sense then please provide solution for that.

Comment: Show how  you *create* the `objPOI.name` string.

Comment: I store JSON object into Model.

Comment: Does the JSON already contain the string "Hof CafÃ©"? Then the error is on the server side. JSON must use UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32 encoding.

Comment: thank you @MartinR its resolved as you said.